# Is there any difference between 'classification' and 'categorization' based on machine learning terminology?

Tags: classification, terminology

When I was learning about classification models, it came to my mind that if there is any difference between "categories" and "classes" on the basis of machine learning terminology? If there is no difference then why do we say classification models, why not categorization models?

Comment: Related: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/9074/is-there-a-difference-between-classification-and-labeling

Comment: Same thing. Just call it classification; it's the more common name for the task.

Comment: @VividD: Thank you for your review but I wanted to clarify my doubt on these terms.

Comment: @Emre Thank you for your comment. But still most of the people think that since they have not read anywhere like 'categorization models' it means they are different.

Comment: That's why you should call it classification.

Answer (score 1):

As noted by @Emre in the comments:

"Same thing. Just call it classification; it's the more common name for the task."

Although there is no difference with respect to machine learning, [this paper](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/774e/ab27b22aa92dfaa9aeeeafbe845058e85f58.pdf) may provide another perspective in detail.